# Parse JSON object containing multiple arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

JSON Object:

```
{"ID":8841,"Data":[{"Type":0,"Value":20.5},{"Type":1,"Value":-2.9},{"Type":2,"Value":12}],"Alert":[{"Type":0,"Value":[1,0,1]},{"Type":1,"Value":[0,0,0]},{"Type":2,"Value":[1,1,0]}]}
```

Is there any way to parse the above object in such a way that each value is stored in its corresponding variable.

In Data Array, 
The value having type = 0 should be stored in the variable (var value_0)
Similarly, the value having type = 1 should be stored in the variable (var value_1) and the value having type = 2 should be stored in the variable (var value_2)

In Alert,
the value array of type 0 should be stored in three variables (alert_type0_condition0,alert_type0_condition1,alert_type0_condition2).
Similarly, the value array of type 1 should be stored in three variables (alert_type1_condition0,alert_type1_condition1,alert_type1_condition2) and the value array of type 2 should be stored in three variables (alert_type2_condition0,alert_type2_condition1,alert_type2_condition2)

Comment: Deserialize it instead of parsing it element by element

Comment: can you show me an example by deserializing it into variables in the way specified in the question?

Comment: Why would you want a variable named `val_0_0`? Or are those just stand-ins for better names?

Comment: You need to do your own research.  I gave you the keyword, so you should be able to find the 2870 posts here on the topic as easily as I did

Comment: @EdPlunkett, yes they are standins

Comment: Are you saying you want to type `var val_O_o = userData.Data[0];` or whatever and so on, or are you asking for some magic one-liner that already has all this logic implemented? If the latter, no. If the former, you already understand what you're looking for far better than anybody else here ever will; just write out the code that does what you want.

Comment: When Im trying to store the first array in the variable value_0 by using var value_0 = userData.Data[0];, I was getting an error: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'Data'.

Answer (score 0):

try jobject instead of deserialising

in case you want to convert json to an object of  class

```
public UserData 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DataDto Data { get; set; }
}

public Data 
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string value{ get; set; }
}
```

and then use the json to convert into object using JavaScriptSerializer

```
string json = //your json {} ;
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var Data = serializer.Deserialize<UserData>(json);
```

Comment: I am able to parse it. I am able to access/store 'ID' in a variable, but not able to access the elements inside Data array or Alert array.

Comment: The downside to parsing is that are 3 arrays in different spots then having to loop thru each to extract each element.

Comment: ok  @TheChosenOne94 ...so you would want to convert a json to c# objects which has many prpoerties like ID & then you would want to use the object ...am i correct ?

Comment: @RohitasBehera yes. I would like to store the arrays present in Data and Alert objects into variables

Comment: Can you store the value in the basis of type. ie, to store the value corresponding to the type= 1 in val1 variable. In the solution that you mentioned, I cannot identify to which type the value belongs to.